# sort an array of associatives arrays in lua

Tags: arrays, sorting, lua, lua-table, aerospike

I have an array that have this structure :

```
[{"value":{"date":"2015-12-27T16:02:38.109Z", "read":"no"}, "key":"56800b9e9669ef7312d94f4c"}, {"value":{"date":"2015-12-30T13:01:30.580Z", "read":"no"}, "key":"5683d5aaec6a8c2428ca1011"},...]
```

I want to sort this array by date in descending order with pagination.

I tried this for example where wholeList is the name of the array and if want to return from indice 1 to 9:

```
 local function compare(a,b)
    return os.date(b["date"])  < os.date(a["date"])
end

function get(rec, ldtBinName, from, to)

if aerospike:exists(rec) then
  local count = llist.size(rec, ldtBinName);
    if count > 0 then
        wholeList = llist.scan(rec, ldtBinName);
        table.sort(wholeList, compare);
        return table.unpack(wholeList , from , to);

    --end if count > 0
    else
    return {};
        --rec['count'] = 0;
        --return empty array

    end
    --end else if count > 0
--end if aerospike exists
else
  return {};--end return empty array
end--end else aerospike exists
```

end

But it didn't work. I also tried to use pairs , but it didn't work.

The error code I got is :

```
 { code: 100,
 message: '/opt/aerospike/usr/udf/lua/timelines.lua:49: bad argument #1 to \'sort\' (table expected, got userdata)',
```

func: 'as_command_parse_udf_error',
  file: 'src/main/aerospike/as_command.c',
  line: 822 }

Note : if I just return 'wholeList' I got the whole array so , I assume that the error is coming when I use table.sort
What am I missing?

Edit : I try another method : [drop and trim a list in aerospike udf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34575773/drop-and-trim-a-list-in-aerospike-udf)

Comment: The table isn't valid Lua code, show your real code,  [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The error message is telling you that `wholeList` is NOT a table, it's a userdata.

Comment: I'm new to lua , what does it mean? how can I fix it?

Comment: You need to make it a table.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you are trying to achieve? If you are using a large ordered list (LDT), it is automatically sorted by the key. If your primary usecase is to list by date, why not use the timestamp as key in milli second precision (no duplicate keys allowed)? Aerospike limits UDF execution to 1 GB, so if you have more than that in your LDT, this manually sorting approach would fail. Also, this wouldn't scale very well with growing list size.

If you tell us your use case we might be able to help you figure out alternative approaches to achieve what you need.

Comment: I want to sort by date in decending order... I want also to not have to take the wholeList and then process it by the client(in my case node.js)... I try to use a table to just return a portion of the wholeList... 'from' and 'to' are determined by node.js to build a pagination system

Comment: I found a solution for list , but it also works with large list : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34575773/drop-and-trim-a-list-in-aerospike-udf