# drop and trim a list in aerospike udf

Tags: arrays, node.js, sorting, udf, aerospike

I try to drop and trim a list to build a pagination system

```
local function createMap(postId, paramDate)
 local m =  map { id = postId, date = paramDate };
 return m;
end



function get(rec, binName, from, to)

    if aerospike:exists(rec) then
        local l = rec[binName]
        if (l == nil) then
            return nil

        else
            local length = #l;
            if (length <= 10 and to <=10) then
                return l;
            elseif (to >= length) then
                local drop = list.drop(l, from); 
                return drop;
            else
                list.trim(l, to);--Remove all elements at and beyond a specified position in the List.
                list.drop(l, from); --Select all elements except the first n elements of the List
                return l;               
            end

        end
    else
    return nil;--end return empty array
    end--end else aerospike exists


end
```

my list has this structure :

```
[{"date":"2016-01-02T19:45:00.806Z", "id":"568828bc49017f16659f6978"}, {"date":"2016-01-02T19:44:56.040Z", "id":"568828b849017f16659f6977"},...]
```

It seems that I can't trim and then drop a list. with 21 elements for example : it first return to element 21 to element 13 , then element 21 to element 4 , then element 3 to element 1

my function in node.js is simple for change 'from' and 'to' I send the 'page' fromm the frontend to node.js and use this function :

```
      var skip = 9 * (page -1);
      var lastIndexToReturn = skip + 9 + 1;
```

so in first request from and to are '0' and '10', then '9' and '19', etc
by using list.trim and list.drop I thought that I can build a pagination system

Comment: Are your list entries small enough so the limited size of a normal list fits well with your usecase? For unlimited lists, Aerospike has Large ordered lists. There are ways to build a pagination without UDF (more performant), would you be interested in such an answer? I understand you are using node.js client? Cheers

Comment: It'a for a list lilited to around 600 elelents...I only use one bin and this structure so it's under 128kb...Indeed U'm using node.js...If you have a better approach I will happy to know it... but i would also know why this code dosn't work? By the way I akso tried with largelist : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34564418/sort-an-array-of-associatives-arrays-in-lua?noredirect=1#comment56891437_34564418

Comment: I also have built a pagination with node where I compare dates and slice to sort an array...But I thought it would be better to do the whole job in lua?

Comment: I can't spot an obvious issue from your code, however the list ops just changed recently and I'm not aware of how the new lua operations behave.

With the go client, I'd use a single multi-op to render the page and page navigation: combine ListGetRange(binname,9*(pageIndex-1),9) and ListSize() in an atomic read op. No trim, clear or copy of the list..
For writes, it depends on if you need ordering. If you want to read a sorted list, create a record UDF that takes an element to insert and finds its correct spot & inserts it there (its atomic). 
For deletes or updates you might need a ...

Comment: a unique key that the list is sorted on.

While UDFs offer great flexibility, if you can avoid them you can achieve even greater performance. With the multi ops command you can do so. E.g. in the above case you can render the first page & know how many pages there are. Benefit of a UDF can be seen with the delete from a sorted list: without that, you'd have to read a complete copy to the cliend, find the position and then write back hoping/checking that nobody else changed list in the meantime. With UDF it's much simpler, saving latency (round-trip) and bandwidth at the ...

Comment: cost of minimal higher cpu usage on server. I'm not sure if NodeJS client already supports the "cdt list ops" (website docs may be behind). If not, you'd have to use single ops for the read part: https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-nodejs/blob/master/docs/operators.md - not atomic but still very good.
Performance with cdt list ops, especially for in-memory namespaces, is exceptional.

Comment: UPDATE: You can use them. See example for multi ops: at aerospike-client-nodejs/examples/operate.js and replace the boring append/incr stuff with new list ops you can find at aerospike-client-nodejs/lib/aerospike.js (line 340~). 
Sorry for the wall of text :)
Note, you need to be prepared what errors these ops return especially parameter error if you try to read with a range completly out of range (e.g. empty list).
Hope this helps. Might be able to put this into a repo on weekend but can't promise that for now.

Answer (score 1):

```
function get(rec, binName, from, to)

    if aerospike:exists(rec) then
        local l = rec[binName]
        if (l == nil) then
            return list()--return empty array

        else
            --first index in lua is 1
            local length = list.size(l)
            local pagination = list()
            if (length < from) then
                return list()
            elseif (length >= from and length <=to) then
                for i=from,length,1 do
                    list.append(pagination, l[i])
                end--end for
                return pagination 
            else
                for i=from,to,1 do
                    list.append(pagination, l[i])
                end--end for
                return pagination
            end     
        end
    else
      return list();--end return empty array
    end--end else aerospike exists


end
--end function
```

I ended by coding this function : to be sure to don't get errors for list index , I get the size of the list and I compare this size to the portion I want to paginate to determine what to return: I don't iterate over the whole array.

Of course it works only if the record is a list
 Note : ensure that the first 'from' coming from the client is 1 because lua arrays begin to 1